# How to warp an UIImage using Open GL or any other method...?

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, uiimage, core-graphics

I am trying to develop an iOS app to make any given image (UIImage) warp on selected locations.

So for this task to be accomplished what should be the rightmost way going forward, for now i'm doing some research on doing this on OpenGL (frankly any heads up on the framework would be nice too).

So finally the requirement is to get the UIImage warp on some given locations. (If x, y coordinates are there)

Answer (score 1):

If you're sufficiently familiar with (or willing to learn) OpenGL, then you could do this:

1. Create a flat, rectangular grid of points to be a mesh that will be displayed with OpenGL.
2. Apply the image to the mesh as a texture.
3. When distorting the image at a particular location, you can just decide which points on the mesh will be affected by the distortion, and move them.

You can push points out from the center, or in toward a center, or shift them all in the same direction.  If the distortion affects a large area, then you change a lot of points (possibly changing those in the center by more than those near the edges of the affected area).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer buddy, indeed this is what i was planning to do in OpenGL, since i'm a noob in that area, a heads up with a small code to start on with would help me a lot, if it's not a big trouble to you....!!!

Thanks again buddy....!!!

Comment: @user1002649 You'll need to look up some tutorials to get up to speed on OpenGL.  Nehe is the place to start: http://nehe.gamedev.net/  Then you might try here: http://zach.in.tu-clausthal.de/projects/bonn/image_manip_ogl/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'warp'.  Do you mean skew it in 3 dimensions?  If so you can adjust the CGAffineTransform for the UIImageView you are displaying it in to get that effect.

If you mean some kind of image processing warp, and you are using iOS 5, you can use Core Image for that.

Comment: Buddy, i've already tried on Core Image, the wrapping libraries that was there in the MAC OS is still not ported for the iOS, so i think it's dead end from that location....!!! :(

Comment: If you try to use Core Image - make sure that your filter is available for your platform. You can see this at the bottom of the all filter description in documentation for Core Image.